# Getting SQL statment sent to server after script finishes generating it with prepared statments

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

I'm trying to trouble shoot a problem with a prepared statement using mysqli in PHP. Is there a way to output the query that is actually sent to the server? For example if the `WHERE` clause to the query is determined from user input, is there a way to see the actual query generated containing the value from the WHERE clause after it's been sanitized? Let me know if the question isn't clear and I'll explain better.

So when `mysqli_stmt_execute($finalQuery);` callled, I want to see the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_info will return info on the last executed query.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

// Stuff to setup query...
$finalQuery = mysqli_prepare($link, $finalQuery);
mysqli_stmt_execute($finalQuery);

var_dump(mysqli_info($link));
```